# Why my hyphens are replacing with "" in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, escaping

I have used below java script to escape few characters like "<>()'/" with "". But it is replacing "-" as well. Can any one suggest me whats going on.

```
    <td colspan=1><input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"  onchange="return escapeSpecialCharacters(this);"
    value="<%=(clientInfo != null) ? escape(clientInfo.getFirstName()) :   ""%>" size="30" maxlength="25"></td>
```

And my javascript is as below

```
private String escapeSpecialCharacters(String value) {
    value = value.replace("<","");
    value = value.replace(">","");
    value = value.replace("(","");
    value = value.replace(")","");
    value = value.replace("'","");
    value = value.replace("/","");  
    return value;
}

public String escape(String value) {
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(value);
}
```

I tried replacing "ISO-8859-1" with  'UTF-8' but it did not work for me..

Comment: You are confusing things, mainly java with javascript.
The first block you posted calls a javascript function. (unless you make a post to the server to only the escapeSpecialCharacters method.
The second block is java, and it works i.e. it does not replace '-'.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes i don't have any prob with escape function. escapeSpecialCharacters method is replacing hyphen with "" . so how can i stop it from replacing "" for "-"

Comment: The method should work fine. Please provide the input you are having issues with.

Comment: Each time when i give - in my input, it becomes empty onchange. If "name-" it becomes name, if "name-name" then it becomes "namename"   and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `escapeSpecialCharacters` should work fine. Even though its written as a Java method the same code should work fine in JavaScript as well. Fro example in the below html as and when you change the text value it retains `-` (hyphen) and removes other symbols.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function escapeSpecialCharacters(obj) {
        var value = obj.value;
        value = value.replace("<","");
        value = value.replace(">","");
        value = value.replace("(","");
        value = value.replace(")","");
        value = value.replace("'","");
        value = value.replace("/","");
        obj.value = value;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"  onchange="return escapeSpecialCharacters(this);" size="30" maxlength="25">
</body>
</html>
```